# Can not do the animation sequence of buttons

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to create an animation buttons. I have 3 buttons. I created an animation as I need to. and applied it to the buttons. but it is performed on all buttons simultaneously. I want her to be followed sequentially. first there is the first button, then the second, then a third.
my animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

in my class onCreateView:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.falling);
        Button kitchenBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonKitchen);
        Button hotelBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotel);
        Button engenerBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEngener);
        kitchenBtn.setAnimation(animation);
        hotelBtn.setAnimation(animation);
        engenerBtn.setAnimation(animation);
```

buttons go from the left edge. I want to start with the first left, then the second and third behind her. Now they do it at the same time.

FULL CODE:

```
public class PurchaseMenu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mAnimationsFinished = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_menu, null);
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.falling);
        final Button kitchenBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonKitchen);
        final Button hotelBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotel);
        final Button engenerBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEngener);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("mylognah","start"+" "+mAnimationsFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //kitchenBtn animation ended
                    hotelBtn.setAnimation(animation);
                } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 1) { //hotelBtn animation ended
                    engenerBtn.setAnimation(animation);
                }
                mAnimationsFinished++; //This would be a member variable
                Log.d("mylognah","finish"+" "+mAnimationsFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        kitchenBtn.setAnimation(animation);
        kitchenBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        hotelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        engenerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: use animation listener.in animation listener its have animation completed listener.for each animation completed listener start next animation.

Comment: I thought about it. Is this the only solution?

Comment: yes that is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set an `AnimationListener` on the `Animation` and keep track of the number of times it finished and start the appropriate next `Animation` like so:

```
final Animation fallingAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.falling);
    final Button kitchenBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonKitchen);
    final Button hotelBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotel);
    final Button engenerBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEngener);
    fallingAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //Kitchen animation ended
                kitchenBtn.setAnimation(null); //Set the animation on the other button to null
                engenerBtn.setAnimation(null); //Otherwise they animate too
                hotelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Make the view visible
                hotelBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                fallingAnimation.start(); //Restart animation. DO NOT FORGET THIS ONE
            } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 2) { //Hotel animation ended. I couldn't figure out why, but this won't work when you try == 1.
                kitchenBtn.setAnimation(null); //Set the animation on the other button to null
                hotelBtn.setAnimation(null); //Otherwise they animate too
                engenerBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Make the view visible
                engenerBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                fallingAnimation.start(); //Restart animation. DO NOT FORGET THIS ONE
            }
            mAnimationsFinished++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    kitchenBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
    hotelBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Make view invisible. Otherwise they're visible before animated
    engenerBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Make view invisible. Otherwise they're visible before animated
```

This way, the `kitchedBtn` will be animated first and when the `Animation` ended, the `onAnimationEnd` method will be called, starting the next `Animation`.

Comment: mAnimationsFinished I do not understand what is it?

Comment: To indicate which animation ended and which animation you have to start next. You could do it with separate booleans too. mAnimationsFinished would be an `int` which is increased every time an animation is finished

Comment: Yes, yes, I do not understand where to declare this variable

Comment: You define it somewhere in your class definition, usually at the start. Something like:
`public class YourClass {`
`private int mAnimationsFinished = 0;`

Comment: Yes, I did just that. The first button is working, the others do not move

Comment: I wrote a log, and it shows that after the first of the animation works onAnimationEnd once

Comment: What do you mean? Is onAnimationEnd only called once or does the wrong animation start?

Comment: the first button is called animation. hereinafter called method onAnimationEnd but on the second and third button animation is not called

Comment: I think I see the problem, I will edit my answer right away. The initial `Animation` variable and the one you get in onAnimationEnd are both called `animation`. I guess something is going wrong there. I updated my code snippet. Could you try it?

Comment: I thought about it and tested it. did not work. Now try again

Comment: Yes, I changed the name of the variable and it did not help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68637/discussion-between-valera-valerianov-and-0xdeadc0de).

Answer (score 0):

using `startOffSet` you can avoid the issue. like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.falling);
        Button kitchenBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonKitchen);
        Button hotelBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotel);
        Button engenerBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEngener);
        kitchenBtn.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.setStartOffset(animation.getDuration());
        hotelBtn.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.setStartOffset(animation.getDuration()*2);
        engenerBtn.setAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a LinearLayout(or any viewgroup) that you want to add these buttons dynamically. You can do like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
     Button button = new Button(context); 
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            linearLayout.addView(button);
            animateButton(button);
         }
     }, BUTTON_DELAY_DURATION * i);
 }
```

and dont forget to call handler.removeCallBacks() to remove runnable instance in onPause();